# How to secure copy 5 most recent files into local directory

Tags: linux, ssh

I have this single line of code

```
scp -r ${server}:${server_dir}/$(ssh ${server} "ls -t ${server_dir} | head -5") logs/ios
```

which when run, will only scp the most recent of the five files, with the following output

```
iosTestOutput_20180831-175508-PDT.tgz                                                                100%  199KB  21.7MB/s   00:00
cp: iosTestOutput_20180831-155546-PDT.tgz: No such file or directory
cp: iosTestOutput_20180831-142509-PDT.tgz: No such file or directory
cp: iosTestOutput_20180831-124259-PDT.tgz: No such file or directory
cp: iosTestOutput_20180831-115001-PDT.tgz: No such file or directory
```

However, I have actually ssh-ed into the target directory and have observed these files exist, so I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: It may be instructive to run `echo scp ... the rest of the command`; you'll see that you told scp to do something different than what you expected. Check out the first argument vs the 2nd and remaining arguments.

Comment: Why did you use `-r` with scp, when you say you're copying *files*? Are you expecting to catch directories? Your examples also look like gzipped tar *files*, not directories.

Comment: Yes I mean secure copy tared files

Answer (score 2):

Only the first file has the absolute path scp needs.

`${server}:${server_dir}/$(ssh ${server} "ls -t ${server_dir} | head -5")` will evaluate to

```
${server}:${server_dir}/iosTestOutput_20180831-175508-PDT.tgz
iosTestOutput_20180831-155546-PDT.tgz
iosTestOutput_20180831-142509-PDT.tgz
...
```

I have used line returns instead of spaces for clarity.

Essentially you need to have a loop over a list generated by using something that outputs the full path for each of the five files. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/240424/162359 might be a good start.

(untested, just a rough sketch) Something like:

```
for bkp in $(ssh ${server} "find ${absolute_path_remote_dir} -type f -exec stat -c '%X %n' {} \; | sort -nr | awk 'NR==1,NR==5 {print $2}'")
do
scp -r ${bkp} logs/ios
done
```

There also may be some option in rsync that will help you accomplish what you're going for more elegantly.

Answer (score 0):

When you ran:

```
scp -r ${server}:${server_dir}/$(ssh ${server} "ls -t ${server_dir} | head -5")
```

... the first (important) thing that happened was that your local shell began interpreting the command substitution here:

```
$(ssh ${server} "ls -t ${server_dir} | head -5")
```

The above command substitution mostly does what you think it does, except that it breaks as soon as there's a space or newline (or tab) in a filename. You might, for instance, have these 5 most recent files:

- `temp file`
- `a`
- `b`
- `c`
- `d`

The `ssh ... ls -t  | head -5` will give you:

```
a
b
c
d
temp file
```

... but the command substitution strips newlines from the output, leaving you with this string being returned:

```
a b c d temp file
```

... which is now indistinguishable from the real, original, filenames.

You may never encounter such a filename, but it's safer to assume safety and never be bitten than the other way around.

As a result, I would suggest a direction in which you safely retrieve the filenames to the local system and then specifically retrieve them:

```
server=server-name-here  ## replace with your values
server_dir=/tmp          ## replace with your values

files=($(ssh "$server" "zsh -c 'print -N -- ${server_dir}/*(om.[1,5])'" 2>/dev/null ) )
for f in ${files[1,5]}
do
  scp "${server}:${f}" logs/ios
done
```

The hardest part is retrieving the remote list of the five most recently-modified files. Here, I'm ssh'ing to the server and invoking zsh in order to use its extensive globbing mechanism to return:

- files from the ${server_dir}
- that are `o`rdered by `m`odification time
- and are regular files (`.`)
- and just the first five: `[1,5]`

The zsh built-in `print` command is used here to return a null-separated -- and null-terminated — list of the resulting files. This null-containing string is passed back through ssh to zsh, who splits the string on nulls and assigns the contents to the `files` array.

We then loop through that array, being careful to grab only the first five elements (as the sixth is a null value), then call `scp` on each of those files in turn.

If you wanted to, you could carefully build up a string of remote filenames (`${server}:${file1} ${server}:${file2} ...`) and call `scp` just once. One possibility could be:

```
scp ${server}:${(qq)^files[1,5]} logs/ios
```

... as that instructs zsh to prepend the string (${server}, which is substituted with your real server name, followed by a colon) to the first five elements of the array. Any filenames from the array are quoted.

Answer (score -1):

Like hhoke1 said you're missing absolute path.

`ls -t | head -5 | xargs readlink -f`

This should give you absolute path for scp but it seems `readlink` can't read input from pipe so I used `xargs`.